# Overlapping CSS elements with different opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to overlap some text fields with transparency over a background that also has transparency, the problem is that the text fields appear opaque, as if they had no transparency applied, how can I manage for both the field and background to appear with a certain transparency?

This is the div that contains everything:

```
#wrapper {                                                                                                                                                              
  width: 940px;                                                                                                                                                         
  margin: 0 auto;                                                                                                                                                       
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);                                                                                                                                       
}
```

And this is my input field:

```
input[type=text] {                                                                                                                                                      
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;                                                                                                                                           
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;                                                                                                                                              
  border-radius: 5px;                                                                                                                                                    
  height: 30px;                                                                                                                                                         
  padding-top: 5px;                                                                                                                                                     
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);                                                                                                                                       
  color: white;                                                                                                                                                         
  border: 1px solid black;                                                                                                                                              
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: see below, just clear any background image, apply a background colour and use the opacity style

Comment: that's transparent... but color being dark you cant see the background

Comment: Chrome and Safari, downloading Firefox to check it it's the same there.

Comment: try changing background color to red for the div

Comment: Changed it, now it does appear transparent, it's the black on black deal it seems. Any way around this? I need them both to appear transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working great, it just doesn't look all that transparent as the .8 transparency of the black background creates a dark grey which perhaps you aren't quite distinguishing from fully opaque. If you want to check this on your local copy, apply a basic background image (e.g. http://purelycss.com/data-uri-tileable-transparent-patterns/) and you should be able to just about see it below your wrapper and input field.

[image: Your code works!]

EDIT: If you're looking to reduce the "black on black" effect, you might want to just reduce the opacity of the 'rgba' - so something more like rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) for example. If not this, changing the colour of the base RBG colour might help you out here. It's one of those things you probably just want to play with and tweak.

Comment: Yeah it's the black on black deal, any way around this to achieve what I want?

Comment: I've updated my post with some information that could help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like it a problem with the stacking of your transparency, to ahcieve a 0.8 transparency on the input box you jsut need to add a further 0.2 transparency to the input (as it has effectively inherited 0.6 of the 0.8 you require from its containing element. see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/e6Z8N/1/

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<input type="text" />
</div>​
```

css:

```
#wrapper {                                                                                                                                                              
width: 940px;                                                                                                                                                         
  margin: 0 auto;                                                                                                                                                       
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
padding:50px;    
}  

input[type=text] {                                                                                                                                                      
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;                                                                                                                                           
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;                                                                                                                                              
  border-radius: 5px;                                                                                                                                                    
  height: 30px;                                                                                                                                                         
  padding-top: 5px;                                                                                                                                                     
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);                                                                                                                                       
color: white;                                                                                                                                                         
  border: 1px solid black;                                                                                                                                              
} ​
```

Comment: new answer, this should work, the opaque you mention is due to the inherited transparency from its parent so reducing the elements opacity by the amount of its container should achieve the effect you are after.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, Joe already suggested this, so sorry I can't accepted your answer now, it does actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clear the default browser styles applied to input elements.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
```